Using ECDSA for Encrypting Data in C#
I'm trying to come up with an interopable crypto algorithm (by interopable I mean the ability to sign/encrypt data in c# using keys generated by JS and vice-versa).
I took ECDSA as a base as it looked modern and well-documented, I also saw sample keyUsage values, implying the encryption support (which I believe works quite well in JS).
I was able to sign/verify signatures in c# using JS generated keys, but c# ECSDA class doesn't seem to support encryption. Is this WIP on MS behalf or we should stick to RSA for encryption (As this answer suggests)?

ECDSA is a digital signature algorithm for elliptic curves.
What you're looking for is public-key authenticated encryption, which uses ECDH key exchange to establish a one-time symmetric encryption key. This symmetric key is then used to perform symmetric encryption using something like AES256 or XSalsa20-Poly1305.
It's not possible to directly encrypt data using EC crypto in the same way that it is  technically possible to do in RSA (although for performance reasons, RSA encryption usually first encrypts a one-time symmetric  encryption key for the recipient, and then uses symmetric encryption).
I think that NaCl's "box" is available for both C# and Javascript and is interoperable. Also see TweetNaCl (JS) and TweetNaCl (C#).

You can use ECDSA keys in an ECIES scheme.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk can I hear more on the subject please?

ECIES is another name for public-key authenticated encryption. Private/public key pairs are the same whether they are used for the purposes of ECDSA or ECDH (as part of ECIES / "box"). You really shouldn't be rolling your own crypto unless you are very sure about what you're doing - which is why I recommend using NaCl / TweetNaCl

Thanks for the answer, I'm happy to accept it - just a small note - what happens to the ECDSA encrypted data in JS? I understand that the holder of the private key can decrypt it in JS, but am I out of chance with decrypting JS encrypted data in c# being in possession of the private key?

@JsCoder I'm not sure I understand your comment. NaCl/TweetNaCl should be interoperable between each of their JS/C# implementations

Andrew what you say makes sense. I was under impression that using the same technology flavor on both side (such as ECDSA P-384) would give me an interopable solution.

You will get interoperability

My question is very simple - if I get data encrypted by P-384 in the browser - can I can decrypt it in C# having the private key anyhow?

@JsCoder TweetNaCl uses Curve25519 instead of P-384. You can encrypt with TweetNaCl in the browser and decrypt it in C#. If you were to modify TweetNaCl to use P-384 you can do what you've just asked, but I would not recommend that you modify it unless you understand exactly what you are doing. Curve25519 is very secure.

I started from having high hopes with V8, but they don't support crypto module, so I had to resort to c#, I hope NaCI works completely on a client side :)

@JsCoder I gave you a link in my answer to pure JS and pure C# implementations of TweetNaCl, so there is no need to hope :)
